# Bokeh Serve HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: python, http, bokeh

How to use HTTPS instead of HTTP for Bokeh Serve ?

The command I use is: `bokeh serve --port 8000`

I'm using an Amazon EC2 with a docker container (exposed and forwarded port 8000, everything works with HTTP). With a Jupyter notebok you can for example use a certfile to allow HTTPS traffic: `--certfile=/.keys/mycert.pem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: The old answer is obsolete. As of Bokeh 1.4, you can terminate SSL directly on the Bokeh server (no Nginx required):

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#ssl-termination

---

---

From the docs... https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Include in your nginx.conf :

```
# redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS (optional)
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name foo.com;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

and run the serve command with `--use-x-headers` flag

```
bokeh serve myapp.py --port 8000 --use-xheaders
```

This tutorial might be helpful:
https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

Comment: This does not answer the question.  All that this does is redirect http:foo.com to http*s*://foo.com.   The bokeh server will not answer to this.