# How can I run Python Bokeh server on HTTPS?

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

I've already read the docs:
[docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html)

and that question:
[overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862782/bokeh-serve-https-instead-of-http)

but found no solution for my issue. I'm using Let'encrypt with certbot. My certs are located at /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname/cert.pem.

I already tried the following expression:
bokeh serve /var/www/domainname/example.py --allow-websocket-origin=domainname:5006 --ssl-certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname/cert.pem

First I got an permission error and after adusting the rights I got another error with the .pem file.

So, what i have to do exactly to get bokeh on ssl?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

letsencrypt certbot is executed as root so its output files are root owned so only root can access your file `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname/cert.pem`

easiest solution would be to login as root and copy those files elsewhere and make them owned by your normal userid ... you are not saying what OS you are on however here is how on linux

```
sudo mkdir /some/tlscertdir  #  make new tls certificate dir

sudo cp -r /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname /some/tlscertdir/ # copy dir from to

sudo chown -R mynormalid:mynormalid /some/tlscertdir # recursively change owner to given userid of given dir
```

then launch your server as normal user id  ( mynormalid )

```
bokeh serve /var/www/domainname/example.py --allow-websocket-origin=domainname:5006 --ssl-certfile /some/tlscertdir/domainname/cert.pem
```

I strongly advise you to avoid running your server as root.  Never run a server as root

Comment: Hi. I got the following error message by doing this: "Cannot start Bokeh server [EBADF]: SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3901)')"